# Passing form data from my view to thank you page

Tags: python, django, forms

Is there a way I can pass data from a form submission over to the 'thank you' page. The reason i'd like to do this is because I have a form on the website, where the user will select multiple fields which all contains different PDF's.

So once the user has submitted the form the idea is to re-direct them to a thankyou page, where they can view the list of pdf/files they have selected on the form.

I hope this is enough info to go on. Here are my views / models.

```
def document_request(request, *args):

   # template = kwargs['name'] + ".html"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ReportEnquiryForm(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
                docrequest = form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('thank_you', kwargs={'id': docrequest.id}))

    else:
        form = forms.ReportEnquiryForm()
        return render_to_response('test.html',{'form':form})

def thank_you(request):


    docrequest = DocumentRequest.objects.get(pk=id)
    return render_to_response('thankyou.html',
                          {'docrequest' : docrequest },                            
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My initial idea was to pass the data to a new view called thank_you. But not this is possible.

```
class DocumentUpload(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length="200")

    document_upload = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/documents")


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name

class DocumentRequest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length="200")

    company = models.CharField(max_length="200")

    job_title = models.CharField(max_length="200")

    email = models.EmailField(max_length="200")

    report = models.ManyToManyField(DocumentUpload)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

form.py

```
class ReportEnquiryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.DocumentRequest

        fields = ('name', 'company', 'job_title', 'email', 'report')
```

If you need anymore info, please ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've saved the user's submission in a DocumentRequest object. So you can pass the ID of that object in the URL when you redirect, and in the `thank_you` view you can get the DocumentRequest and render the list.

**Edit** The idea is to make the thank_you page like any other view that accepts a parameter from the URL:

```
url(r'thanks/(?P<id>\d+)/$, 'thank_you', name='thank_you')
```

and so the POST part of the form view becomes:

```
if form.is_valid():
    docrequest = form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('thank_you', kwargs={'id': docrequest.id}))
```

and thank_you is:

```
def thank_you(request, id):

    docrequest = DocumentRequest.objects.get(pk=id)
    return render_to_response('thankyou.html',
                              {'docrequest' : docrequest },                            
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Second edit**

As others have suggested, this makes it possible for anyone to see the request. So a better solution is to put it in the session:

```
    docrequest = form.save()
    request.session['docrequest_id'] = docrequest.id
```

and in thank_you:

```
def thank_you(request):
    if not 'docrequest_id' in request.session:
        return HttpResponseForbidden    
    docrequest = DocumentRequest.objects.get(request.session['docrequest_id'])
```

Comment: Hi Dan thanks for your reply. I'm going to sounds like a real n00b now. Is there a way you could give me an example? This is all new to me and i'm trying to make sense of it all.

Comment: Note: the thank you page will be accessible by any person. If you don't want the user to return to the thank you page, you can use the session and delete the session variable after the user visits the page. Then you won't need to do these changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'm getting this error. 'The view contact_enquiries.views.document_request didn't return an HttpResponse object.' Is this because I need return an empty form when getting? If so, how do i go about doing that?

Comment: You still need the `else` part of that view, I didn't show it for the sake of brevity.

Comment: I've updated my post with the updated views. I've not touched the else statement which is weird?

Comment: You *have* changed the else. Not only is it now indented too far, but you have brought it up above the redirect statement, and removed the render_to_response. You should undo those changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as Daniel Roseman said but in this case the thank you pages can be accessed by anyone with the Ids.

Some ways to pass data between views are the following(the list is not mine.):

```
GET request - First request hits view1->send data to browser -> browser redirects to view2
POST request - (as you suggested) Same flow as above but is suitable when more data is involved
Using django session variables - This is the simplest to implement
Using client-side cookies - Can be used but there is limitations of how much data can be stored.
Maybe using some shared memory at web server level- Tricky but can be done.
Write data into a file & then the next view can read from that file.
If you can have a stand-alone server, then that server can REST API's to invoke views.
Again if a stand-alone server is possible maybe even message queues would work.
Maybe a cache like memcached can act as mediator. But then if one is going this route, its better to use Django sessions as it hides a whole lot of implementation details.
Lastly, as an extension to point 6, instead of files store data in some persistent storage mechanism like mysql.
```

The simplest way is to use sessions. Just add the id to the session and redirect to the thank you view, you read the id value and query the db with that id.